# SSH not returning exit code

Tags: shell, unix, ssh, error-handling, aix

Following is the SSH code to perform cleanup activities on remote location

```
#!/bin/ksh -x
ssh "$RFTPUSERID@$RFTPSERVER" /bin/bash 2>> "${LOGFILE}" << EOF
shopt -s extglob
cd "${ARCHIVEPATH}"
find  "${ARCHIVEPATH}" -type f -mtime "+${ARCHIVERETENTIONDAYS}" -name "${WLDCRD}*" -exec rm -rf {} \;
date="\$(date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')"
for file in "${ARCHIVEPATH}"!(*.gz) 
do
    newFile="\${file}\$date"
    echo "\${newFile}";
    mv "\$file" "\${newFile}";
    gzip "\${newFile}";
done
exit
EOF

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
echo "Success"
fi
```

I want to capture the exit code to check for failures using $?

But on running echo $?, it returns nothing

How to get the return code of the SSH command or is there a better way to do error handling for SSH

Comment: Where are you doing `echo $?`? That would be a serious shell bug if you are really getting *no* output.

Comment: once you exeucte ANY other command the value of `$?` changes, so best to explicity capture that value, like `ssh .... ; ssrRet=$?; oterhStuff`. Good luck.

Comment: Please see examples on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @SharadR.Telkar : _running echo $?, it returns nothing_  : What is "nothing"? I would expect it to print `0` to stdout.

Answer (score 1):

From the ssh man page:

> EXIT STATUS ssh exits with the exit status of the remote command or with 255 if an error occurred.

You provide the remote command as HERE doc. The last command in this remote script is

```
exit
```

which is equivalent to

```
exit 0
```

Therefore, you always return a zero exit code and your program gets this in its `$?`.